# What might cause an infinite loop error

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming

I am working on a network programming and I have this code

```
void WorkHandler::workLoop(){
.
.
.

while(1){
    if(remainLength >= MAX_LENGTH)
        currentSentLength = send(client->getFd(), sBuffer, MAX_LENGTH, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    else
        currentSentLength = send(client->getFd(), sBuffer, remainLength,MSG_NOSIGNAL);


if(currentSentLength == -1){
    log("WorkHandler::workLoop, connection has been lost \n");
    break;
}
sBuffer += currentSentLength;
remainLength -= currentSentLength;

if(remainLength == 0)
    break;
     }
}
```

Also, I am creating a child thread like this

```
bool WorkHandler::initThreads(){

for(int i=0; i < m_maxThreads; i++){
    pthread_t *thread(new pthread_t);
    m_workThreadList.push_back(thread);

    if(pthread_create(thread, NULL, runWorkThread, reinterpret_cast<void *>(this))!=0){
        log("WorkHandler::initThreads, pthread_create error \n");
        return false;
    }

    pthread_detach(*thread);
}

return true;
```

}

```
void* WorkHandler::runWorkThread(void *delegate){
    printf("WorkHandler::runWorkThread, called\n");

    WorkHandler *ptr = reinterpret_cast<WorkHandler*>(delegate);
    ptr->workLoop();
    return NULL;
}
```

I am running this code on gdb and it doesn't blow up but it gets stuck at the second send function in the if then else loop. I put log statements every single line and it prints a log right above the second send function and stopped.

```
currentSentLength = send(client->getFd(), sBuffer, remainLength, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

What might cause this problem and how do I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I doubt it's your main problem, but that while should really say `while (remainLength > 0)`. I shudder whenever I see `while(true)` or equivalent. Although it might be related to remainlength going negative for some reason; you're only breaking if it's ==0.

Comment: check that the client(s) read the data

Comment: I guess this is too trivial, but the while loop will get stuck if currentSentLength is 0 or negative, or if remainLength gets negative.

Comment: Are `remainLength` and `MAX_LENGTH` of same type ? (signed or unsigned). Often the comparison happens between signed and unsigned and it results either always true or always false.

Comment: Is there anyone who can modify the send part of my code? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With blocking IO send will `block` if the kernel buffer is full and will block untill the clients have read the data. Do you send large chunks? If so, check your client.

If you don't trust clients (they can abuse this to do denial of service attacks) there are a couple of ways to do this properly: poll (with timeout) on the sockets for writeability, send with timeout, use nonblocking I/O, ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're calling send() with a negative size...
Your test to exit the while should be
remainLength <= 0
and not
remainLength == 0

Comment: @yi_H: Because `remainLength -= currentSentLength;` could become negative, depending on what `send()` returns.

Comment: It does not fix this problem. I changed the condition of while loop to "remainLength > 0" but it still gets stuck at the second send function...How do I fix this?

Comment: humm... try replacing the send() with your own function that just traces its parameters... this way you'll be able to pinpoint where the problem is, either inside send() or doing the loop...

Comment: Maybe this can also help you (http://linux.die.net/man/2/send): When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket, send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in non-blocking I/O mode. In non-blocking mode it would return EAGAIN in this case. The select(2) call may be used to determine when it is possible to send more data.

Comment: So according to my previous comment, check that the send buffer is not full and that the socked is ok to send data...